# Adding standard libraries on Eclipse CDT on Mac OSX

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-cdt

I can't get eclipse cdt on my MacBook to recognize strings or cout or any standard includes like it does when I use linux. How do I configure it to reference the correct libraries?